What could be the reason our app doesn't show up when searching on Google Play
So this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.dkent.workreporting
When searching for it on the store, either just the name or the company name it doesn't show up. But if I search for it on Google or Duckduckgo I can find it there, I can press "See in Play Store app", it opens the play store app and I can install it from there. And so can our customers.
I have a Xiaomi Redmi Note 11 Pro, we have a Google Pixel 2XL at work. Both of which the app should be available on. The customer has also reported that it doesn't really appear on any devices. Which is weird because according to Play Console there's 19536 supported devices. Those two among them.
I have absolutely no idea what is wrong. As far as I can tell everything is fine on the Play Console. No errors, warnings, or messages about anything.
I did also contact Googles support, but I figured I might as well ask in here (and update when I get a response from Google)

If I try to download dk.dkent.workreporting I can see in meta data that the app seems to be country restricted (restriction=2).

I can see it's set to Denmark. The two locations you're seeing is Greenland and the Faroe Islands. My phones Google Play is also set to Denmark, and I assume our Danish customers workers also are :v


Indexing Time
New App: If the app was just published, it may take some time to be indexed and appear in search results.
Update Propagation: Changes to app metadata (e.g., title, description, keywords) can take time to propagate through Google Play’s search index.
App Name and Keywords
App Title: If your app’s title doesn’t contain commonly searched terms, it may rank lower in search results.
Description: Ensure your app’s description includes relevant keywords that users might search for.
Metadata Quality: Poor or incomplete metadata can hurt visibility.
Localized Metadata: If your app targets multiple languages, ensure metadata is properly localized.


But if I search for the app on the play stores website it'll be the first result. It can't be 1 since the app has been out since around 2017 or -18. 2 doesn't make much sense when you can find it on their website, but not in their app

@JaDa Was the app updated regularly? Because old apps that doesn't meet the targetSDK requirements are hidden and only available to users that use old devices or those who have it installed (or had it installed once).

Yeah I've thought about that too. But the app is incredibly simple and we only update it to match new API versions
